# Having both speakers and headphones plugged in and switching in software on-the-fly with XFCE (on Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, pulseaudio, pipewire, wireplumber

I am running Arch with XFCE and my audio is pipewire + wireplumber + pavucontrol-qt.

I need something similar to: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Having_both_speakers_and_headphones_plugged_in_and_switching_in_software_on-the-fly.

The difference is that I have a digital output connected to an amplifier instead of analog speakers from my soundcard, and the HDMI digital sound output to my monitor.

The behaviour that I want to have is for there to always be *three* outputs/sinks for me to choose in my XFCE-pulse-audio panel plugin: Headphones, Digital Out, and HDMI and that I can switch between them by clicking (see: https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin/start).

This works out-of-the-box on GNOME.

Currently plugging in headphones removes the digital out, and I have to fiddle with the configuration tab in the volume control mixer (pavucontrol) to switch it back by changing the active profile from Analog Stereo Output to Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output. In this configuration, if my amp turns off sound starts coming out of my monitor.

I looked at config files at /usr/share/alsa-card-profile/paths/ to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could try using ajsnap to save your config and then recall it on demand.

https://aj-snapshot.sourceforge.io/